# Troubleshooting the error from FIDO conformance tool(UAF), How can I solve this error?

Tags: fido, uaf

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6aP.png)

I'm currently dealing with this error for days. I don't know how I can figure out what is the KeyID and the solution for it.To me it doesn't make sense that since the tool itself creates the KeyID, I have no option to add it in my disallowedKeyIDs.. Any thoughts will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The tools are trying to register three different credentials with the server. The server must return a disallow policy with all the registered KeyIDs.

The tools are sending username in the Get/Sign Get/Register, so you can track which username keyID associated with.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your apply. I have checked the request and response following your commend  and then I found out that there is no username received within the payload. Can that be the root of this error?

Comment: Tools use cookies for session keeping. There will be username for initial request, and following requests are using cookies for session.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm understanding this concept correctly. Does that mean from the initial request, there will be a single username, and KeyID is also created as a pair? How do we track down the username and KeyID then? I can print out the username but not the KeyID. It almost feels like it's an unicorn or smtg..